# Any way to do the equivalent of $unionWith in mongodb 4.2?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to run an aggregation pipeline on two collections, `gadgets` and `gadgets-archive`. I'd like to treat the two as a single collection. Mongodb 4.4 has `$unionWith`. Any way to do this on Mongodb 4.2? The `gadgets-archive` collection is very large, so inserting into a new one isn't an option.

Comment: It should be possible via a workaround, can you share some sample data, along with the expected output?

Comment: Two identical collections.  Let's say, both have `_id`, `name` and `price`.  Get average price grouped by name, among both collections, as if they were joined into one. I am just making it up as I go.

Comment: Better yet, execute an arbitrary aggregation pipeline for both, as if they were one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this workaround:

```
db.gadgets.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "gadgets": [],
      "archive": [
        {
          "$limit": 1
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "gadgets-archive",
            "pipeline": [],
            "as": "archives"
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": "$archives"
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$archives"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      total: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$archive",
          "$gadgets"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$total"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$total.item",
      "average": {
        "$avg": "$total.price"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lVKNjasAIU4)

Here, we proceed as follows:

1. We use `$facet`, to store docs from `gadgets` collection in `gadget` variable and from the `gadgets-archive` collection, in an `archive` variable.
2. Then we concatenate the two arrays.
3. Then we unwind the combined array.
4. Finally we calculate the average, by grouping them by name.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Incredible. Kind of unreadable, given the actual length of the second aggregation (that I modeled with `$avg`), but I didn't think it can be done at all!

Comment: As I said, it's a workaround. Do you want me to add more explanation?

Comment: I get it, thanks. $facet with $lookup all limit 1, very clever. I wonder how performance is going to be, given the size of both collections (and it would probably make sense to swap them, so that we aren't unwinding the larger collection).

Comment: In terms of performance, yes swapping collections, so that we unwind the shorter one makes sense.  Also, if there are filters on the fields that need to be applied, they should be applied before `$facet`, in the source collection, and in the pipeline variable of `$lookup`, so that the indexes of the respective collections come into the picture. Without filters, the current scenario might not be as performant, because grouping itself doesn't use any indexes.